# Receive HTTP requests on phone (Ionic 2)

Tags: http, express, ionic-framework

I'm in front of a big problem, I have an API using Node.JS and Express and an app running on Ionic 2.

At the moment, the Ionic app can send HTTP requests to the API

I want to know if there is a way for the API to send HTTP requests to the smartphone app (for example new user connected to the API etc...)

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You should use push notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, app can send HTTP requests to the API is because that the app know the IP address and a port number. And the server is listening requests to that port.

However, the server doesn't know the IP address of phone, and the phone doesn't listen to a port. So, the API can't send HTTP requests to app actively.

But, you can use TCP instead of HTTP. TCP is a keep-alive connection. App and API can send message to each other in many times. Also, app should be the one who start the connect firstly.

Or, the app use HTTP to ask the server for data at regular time(polling).

Comment: thanks ! if I know the IP address of the phone, is there a way to do it ?

Comment: Is there a way to use socket.io to do that ?

Comment: You need make the app listening in a certain port, so that API can request this IP and port. @AlvinFREY

Comment: I haven't known that before, but it seems feasible according to its introduction. It uses websocket to make a keep-alive connection(websocket is a new protocol based on TCP).